# Is the uniform boundedness principle not trivially obvious?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I read that the uniform boundedness principle is one of the big theorems in functional analysis. However after looking at it, I'm not sure what is so significant about it, it seems trivially obvious.

The uniform boundedness principle states that if we have a family of operators $F = (T_n)$ from a Banch space $X$ to a normed space $Y$ that are pointwise bounded, then they are uniformly bounded in the operator norm.

This seems trivial, if the family of operators is pointwise bounded then we know that for any $x$ we take in the domain $X$, the resulting value after applying one of the operators from $F$ to it will also be a finite value. So clearly the operator norm (which accounts for all $x \in X$ and $T_n \in F$) will also be finite.

Am I missing something here, why is this theorem so significant and considered an important result?

Comment: Hint: imagine a hypothetical scenario where $x_k$ is a sequence of points in $X$ such that $|| x_k || = 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$, and $\sup_{T \in F}||T(x_k)|| = k$ for each $k$.

Comment: @KennyWong Ok so for any $x_k$ we have $\sup_{T in F} ||T(x_k)|| = k$ and therefore as $k$ can be arbitrarily large $\sup_{T in F} ||T(x_k)|| = \infty$. So in your example we don't have pointwise boundedness, and thus we can't apply the principle of uniform boundedness. I don't think I understand what your example is supposed to illustrate?

Comment: For any particular _fixed_ $x_k$, we have $\sup_{T \in F} || T(x_k) || = k$. As I said, $k$ is _fixed_. Now, $k$ is a finite number. So $\sup_{T \in F} || T(x) ||$ is finite at the point $x= x_k$, for any choice of $x_k$.

Comment: However, $\sup_{T \in F} || T || = \sup_{T \in F} \left( \sup_{|| x|| = 1} || T(x) || \right) = \infty$.

Comment: @KennyWong So for each fixed $x_k$ we have that $\sup_{T \in F} || T(x_k) || = k < \infty$. So have pointwise boundedness. Therefore we can apply the uniform boundedness principle and we have that $\sup_{T \in F} ||T|| < \infty$. But this contradicts your your statement that $\sup_{T \in F} ||T|| = \infty$. So it seems that the uniform boundedness principle $\textit{doesn't}$ apply for some reason in your example. Why doesn't it apply? What you are trying to demonstrate with this particular example?

Comment: Excellent. The principle of uniform boundedness proves that my hypothetical example can never occur!

Comment: @KennyWong Ok it seems there is more to this theorem that I originally thought! So the principle of uniform boundedness can be used to show that there are restrictions on the bounded linear operators we can define..that some operators are 'impossible'?

Comment: Well, it shows that families of operators of the kind I described are impossible. At least, impossible under two conditions: (i) each individual $T$ is continuous, and (ii) the domain $X$ is Banach. The answer by H. H. Rugh gives a FANTASTIC example of how the theorem fails if you don't assume (ii).

Comment: @KennyWong I'm thinking I am getting a good grasp on the principle now, and how it demonstrates the importance of completeness. Yes Rugh's answer is very nice. One final thing I don't get is how the completeness of $X$ contributes to your hypothetical example being impossible?

Comment: Completeness is important because it is used as an assumption in the proof of the theorem. The proof uses the Baire category theorem, which only works for complete metric spaces.

Comment: @KennyWong Ah yes I get it now, we have: completeness $\to X$ is a Banach space $\to$ the uniform boundedness principle holds $\to$ the operator $T$ as you defined it is not possible under these conditions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a family of operators from a normed space to a normed space that are pointwise bounded then they need not be uniformly bounded. It is crucial that the domain is complete (and one uses some version of Baire's category theorem in the proof). But I suppose a concrete example is better.
Let $$V=\{ x=(x_k)_{k\geq 1} : \sup_{k\geq 1} k |x_k| < +\infty \}$$
and equip $V$ with the uniform norm: $\|x\| = \sup_{k\geq 1} |x_k|$.
Then $V$ is not a Banach space (not complete). On the other hand,
the family $F_k(x) = k x_k$, $k\geq 1$ is a family of pointwise bounded operators from $V$ to ${\Bbb R}$: By definition of $V$, for every $x\in V$ there is $c(x)<+\infty$ so that 
 $$ |F_k(x)| \leq c(x), \ \ k\geq 1 $$
so the family is indeed point wise bounded. However, 
 $$ \|F_k\| = k$$
(take an $x$ with $1$ in the $k$'th place, zero elsewhere) so it is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: What a fantastic example!

Comment: Thanks for the example, I see the point of the principle now!